# How can I build an Objective-C static library to distribute as a single binary and header file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, linker, header, static-libraries

I'm building a static library, `MyLibrary`, for iOS in Objective-C that bundles together a dozen useful classes, each with its own .h file.  I'd like to distribute `MyLibrary` as a single compiled binary, `libMyLibrary.a`, and a single .h header file, `MyLibraryAPI.h`.  `MyLibraryAPI.h` has a dozen `#import` statements, one for each of `MyLibrary`'s dozen public classes.  Developers who want to include `MyLibrary` in their host projects should only have to include the `libMyLibrary.a` binary and the `MyLibraryAPI.h` header.  This is the goal.

So I have set the `Role` of each public class in the `MyLibrary` Xcode project to `Public` and built `libMyLibrary.a` successfully using Xcode command line build utils and `lipo`.  Then, I manually included all of the dozen `MyLibrary` header files along with `libMyLibrary.a` in a host project, and the host project can use the public `MyLibrary` classes with no problem.  Awesome!

The problem is if I remove those dozen header files and use `MyLibraryAPI.h` instead (as is my goal), the host project's classes can no longer find the `MyLibrary` header files referenced in `MyLibraryAPI.h`.  Instead, at compile time, I get errors like: `MyAwesomeThingDelegate.h: No such file or directory...` for each `MyLibrary` class that I try to `#import` in `MyLibraryAPI.h`.  I have a folder in my host project root directory called `lib` and in host project build settings have set the recursive header search path to `lib/**` and in Library Search Path, set a recursive path to `lib/**`.

I'd love to hear suggestions from the community on how to correctly set the host project's search paths so that I only need to include `libMyLibrary.a` and `MyLibraryAPI.h` to use the `MyLibrary` classes.  Or if I'm doing something wrong, I'd love to hear another suggestion to achieve my goal of distributing a single binary and a single API header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had the same challenge and I've come with the following solution:

First, I tried to hide as many implementation details as possible. For that reason, I usually built pairs of classes: one class is the public interface and the other one the private implementation. The public class has only one member instance: the pointer to the implementation. The private class has just a forward declaration.

```
@class MyViewImpl;

@interface MyView : UIView
{
    @private
    MyViewImpl* _internal;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) CGRect highlightArea;
- (void) startAnimation;

@end
```

Second, I put all the public declarations into a single header file. It's as comfortable to work with as with separate header file, but it works. The only imports that are left, are import of iOS stuff, such as:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
```

Comment: Is this really the best / only way to do this?  There is no way just to use import statements on a consolidated header file?  You have to "manually" declare an interface to each class that you want to expose in the API header?  I don't know much about linking, so I apologize if these questions are really basic...

Answer (score 1):

I'm giving a second answer here with a different approach.

The way Objective C works is, that the compiler needs the full declaration (i.e. the header files) of all the classes that the users of your library will directly call. The library file (the .a file) only contains the compiled code and no declaration. It will only be used by the linker, which is one of the last steps of building an application.

[Programming languages like C or C++ are the same. Programming languages like Java or C# however store meta information about classes in the compiled code so they don't need no header files, just the .jar or .dll file.]

So one approach would be to give the .a and a directory full of header files to your user. They then add the .a file to their project, add a single #import statement wherever they use your classes and add the path to the header file directory to their build settings (it's called Header Search Paths).

Comment: Sure, this makes sense, but this approach would make me abandon my design goal of distributing `MyLibrary` as two files, the binary .a file and a single header .h file.  Thanks so much for sharing your expertise.

Comment: I'd be glad to hear about the solutions of other people. But I'm afraid there's no really beautiful solution with Objective C.