# iphone +static liabrary

Tags: iphone

I have made a static library and I have to implement all header files in another project that includes my static library.

Is there any way that I do not have to implement all header files?

I have read [How can I build an Objective-C static library to distribute as a single binary and header file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4564063/how-can-i-build-an-objective-c-static-library-to-distribute-as-a-single-binary-an) and I still cannot solve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

http://www.icodeblog.com/2011/04/07/creating-static-libraries-for-ios/

Comment: ya but still in it .header files are implemented but i don't want to implement header files